# Android Kotlin app not displaying or hiding an image based on received bluetooth data

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, visibility

My app connects via bluetooth to an Arduino, that has an LED on board that is controlled by a button. The LED is either on or off. And when that state changes, the Arduino will transmit a 1(on) or 0(off).

My app/phone connects fine. I can see those LED state changes in the app's logs.

**LOGCAT**

> 2019-12-04 09:36:41.271 30645-32215/com.example.pigcatcher I/MainActivity: 1
>
> 2019-12-04 09:36:42.288 30645-32215/com.example.pigcatcher I/MainActivity: 0
>
> 2019-12-04 09:36:43.395 30645-32215/com.example.pigcatcher I/MainActivity: 1
>
> 2019-12-04 09:36:44.207 30645-32215/com.example.pigcatcher I/MainActivity: 0

This function listens for those LED state change messages:

```
private fun readBlueToothDataFromMothership(bluetoothSocket: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket) {
    val bluetoothSocketInputStream = bluetoothSocket.inputStream
    val buffer = ByteArray(256)
    var bytes: Int

    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = bluetoothSocketInputStream.read(buffer)       
            val readMessage = String(buffer, 0, bytes)

            Log.i(LOGTAG, readMessage)

            if (readMessage.equals(1)) {
                imageView_mothership_LED_state.showOrHideImage(true)
            } else {
                imageView_mothership_LED_state.showOrHideImage(false)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called from the while loop above.

```
private fun View.showOrHideImage(imageShow: Boolean) {
    visibility = if (imageShow) {
        View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        View.INVISIBLE
    }
}
```

This is the image in question from the .xml file.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_mothership_button_pushed"
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="204dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:contentDescription="Star"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_led_off"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />
```

This is where my question/problem comes in. This does not happen. As shown in the logs above, the app is seeing those LED state change messages. But nothing is happening in the app. I'm sure, I've set this up incorrectly, but I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

**EDIT**

I forgot to include the following inner class, where the "readBlueToothDataFromMothership" function is called from.

```
private inner class ConnectThread(device: BluetoothDevice): Thread() {
    private var newSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)

    override fun run() {
        try {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Connecting bluetoothSocket")
            handler.post {
                connectedOrNotTextView.text = getString(R.string.connecting)
                connectToDeviceButton.isEnabled = false
            }
            bluetoothSocket = newSocket
            bluetoothSocket.connect()
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Socket connected")
            handler.post {
                connectedOrNotTextView.text = getString(R.string.connected)
                connectToDeviceButton.isEnabled = false; disconnectButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        }catch (e1: Exception){
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error connecting bluetoothSocket, $e1")
            handler.post {
                connectedOrNotTextView.text = getString(R.string.connection_failed)
                connectToDeviceButton.isEnabled = true; disconnectButton.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
        readBlueToothDataFromMothership(bluetoothSocket)
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

As pointed out in the comments, readMessage is a string and not an int.

So, I changed:

```
if (readMessage.equals(1) {
```

to:
    if (readMessage == "1") {

No it seems to be actually hitting the View.showOrHideImage() function. However, the app now crashes with the following:

> 2019-12-04 12:49:53.983 19718-19987/com.example.pigcatcher I/MainActivity: 1
>
> 2019-12-04 12:49:54.018 19718-19987/com.example.pigcatcher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
>       Process: com.example.pigcatcher, PID: 19718
>       android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>
> > at  com.example.pigcatcher.MainActivity.showOrHideImage(MainActivity.kt:102)
> >
> > at com.example.pigcatcher.MainActivity.readBlueToothDataFromMothership(MainActivity.kt:89)
> >
> > at com.example.pigcatcher.MainActivity.access$readBlueToothDataFromMothership(MainActivity.kt:31)
> >
> > at com.example.pigcatcher.MainActivity$ConnectThread.run(MainActivity.kt:173)

Line 102 points to the following:

```
visibility = if (imageShow) {
```

And line 173 is:

```
readBlueToothDataFromMothership(bluetoothSocket)
```

Which is from the ConnectThread() inner class.

I think, I'm calling that function from the wrong place?

Comment: You can only update a view from main threadrunOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
    }
});

Comment: Yes. I'm now troubleshooting this part. If I move that call into the main thread(onCreate()), but doing that I get a lateinit bluetoothSocket is not initialized error. Which confuses me. I am struggling to figure out where to initialize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ***readMessage*** is a ***String*** as per code below

```
val readMessage = String(buffer, 0, bytes)
```

**Your condition**

```
if (readMessage.equals(1)) {
    imageView_mothership_LED_state.showOrHideImage(true)
} else {
    imageView_mothership_LED_state.showOrHideImage(false)
}
```

**should be**

```
imageView_mothership_LED_state.showOrHideImage(readMessage == "1")
```

**OR (for threads other than UI/Main Thread)**

```
imageView_mothership_LED_state.post {
    imageView_mothership_LED_state.showOrHideImage(readMessage == "1")
}
```

Comment: This confuses me. showOrHideImage() is a boolean though. Are you saying that function is not needed?

Comment: I've just shortened the if-else. Upvote if this solves your problem.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what you are suggesting. The change you suggest does nothing but breaks when it calls the function showOrHideImage().

Comment: Ok. From edits, I see that your code is running on some thread other than UI Thread. I have added code for that in OR section. You might want to check that.

Comment: Interesting. I added your suggestion to the OR section above and the app no long is crashing. But the image is not behaving as I would want or expect, but it is definitely progress. Thank you very much for sticking with this. I am learning and this sort of help is priceless to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
val readMessage = "1"
if(readMessage.equals(1)) System.out.println("true")
else System.out.println("false")
O/P -> false
```

If I Understand from your code is you are getting String as 1 and you are comparing it with Int 1 due to which it is returning false and your condition is not getting executed

Try to put a log and print the value in readMessage that will help to solve your problem

Comment: I am logging readMessage

val readMessage = String(buffer, 0, bytes)
Log.i(LOGTAG, readMessage)

Which is showing up in the logs as displayed above.

Comment: Try to change the if condition to if(readMessage.equals("1")) and check

Comment: I did that. I edited my original post to show what happened. It now appears to be hitting the the function to make the change. But it crashing with a "CalledFromWrongThreadException".

Comment: You can only update a view from main thread runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread"); write your code here
    }
});

Comment: This issue is moving on from the initial problem. I'm gonna mark your answer as the answer. Due to it cluing me in to change from expecting an int vs. a string. I'll start a new post if I need more help figuring out how to deal with the non initialized lateinit varible.